# Locating Javascript libraries for FFI

Tags: haskell, ffi, ghcjs

I am digging through `ghcjs-jquery` code to see how `JavascriptFFI` works. What I am trying to figure out is that once you define FFI import type signature for a JS function, how do you help `ghcjs` locate the file containing the function.

Checking [`Internal.hs`](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-jquery/blob/master/JavaScript/JQuery/Internal.hs) and Cabal configuration, I don't see any way to specify the path of the JQuery JS files. I also looked around for documentation on `JavascriptFFI` feature but haven't found anything. I will appreciate pointers on how to do Javascript FFI in `ghcjs` for any JS library. There must be some command-line option to `ghcjs` to tell it where to locate the `js` files.

I am planning to play with [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) library functions after I figure out `JavascriptFFI` feature of `ghcjs`.

Comment: But why does GHCJS have to be able to "find" the functions? It just generates calls to them; then, if at runtime the functions are loaded, the calls will succeed. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of loading those Javascript files yourself in the page that you use the GHCJS-generated Javascript. GHCJS doesn't need to find the actual definition of the referenced Javascript functions -- it takes for granted whatever type you add in your `foreign` declaration.